# Cakephp 3 Unknown Email error

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I wanted to ask about sending emails in cakephp3.

I am using cakephp3 docs, and configured everything as example shows.

But, when I try to send mail, this error appears:

> Could not send email: unknown

```
//app.php
'EmailTransport' => [

    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Mail',
        // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.om',
        'port' => 465,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
    ],
],
```

ContactController:

```
public function contact() {

    if (isset($this->request->data) AND ($this->request->is('post'))) {
        $email = new Email('default');
        if ($email->from(['mymail@gmail.com' => 'My Site'])->to('othermail@gmail.com')->subject('Hello')->send('Message')) {
            //pr( 'ok');
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a generic error message (, which may have many reasons, in my opinion)? it has no value in context of debug.

Comment: Please add "the code to send emails" in your question

Comment: btw, here same issue is addressed https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/3982#issuecomment-49091233

Comment: Please correct the host to smtp.gmail.com

Comment: if u have found the solution can u please provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use an SMTP server, but you've configured to use the `Mail` transport!

The `className` option should be set to `Smtp`. The host should probably also be different (`ssl://` prefixed), or you should enable TLS, please be sure that you read through the questions/answers found with the search linked below.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Email > Configuring Transports](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#configuring-transports)**
- **[https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[cakephp]+gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+gmail)**

Answer (score 0):

The host name in default configuration is incorrect.

it should be

```
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
```

instead of

```
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.om',
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's always forgotten is the Email profiles

```
   `'Email' => [
    'default' => [
        'transport' => 'gmail', //this allows the email class to use the gmail settings
        'from' => 'youremail@gmail.com',
        //'charset' => 'utf-8',
        //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
    ],
    ],`
```

And by the way you can set up multiple profiles for the like testing, development etc

Answer (score -1):

```
use Cake\Mailer\Email;

Email::configTransport('gmail', [
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'className' => 'Smtp',
    'tls' => true
]);
```

Yous this code : Replace My@gmail.com and Secret with you credentials offcourse and after that use you code it will work.